# Nginx + Rails + sendfile : file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, x-accel-redirect

Been having a problem setting up sendfile for nginx+rails lately. We have one kind of file download that's already handled by nginx, and we wanted to add a second rule to deal with another kind of files at another location, but we have no success so far.

#### Ruby controller :

```
def download_file
  send_file("/srv/www/myapp/shared/tmp/directory/file.zip")
end
```

#### Environment configuration file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ..  
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
  # ..
end
```

#### Nginx configuration :

```
upstream myapp {
  server 127.0.0.1:9292;
}

server {
  listen 80;    
  server_name myapp.tld;

  client_max_body_size 10M;

  root /srv/www/myapp/current/public; 

  # This first block works perfectly
  location /__working_file {
    internal;
    alias /var/lib/myapp;
  }    

  # This second block does not work at all
  location /__new_files {
    internal;
    alias /srv/www/myapp/shared/tmp/directory;
  }

  location / {
    root /srv/www/myapp/current/public;
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;
    # This first rule works perfectly
    proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping /var/lib/myapp/=/__working_file/;
    # This second rule doesn't
    proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping /srv/www/myapp/shared/tmp/directory/=/__new_files/;

    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;

    proxy_pass http://myapp;
  }
}
```

#### Result

When accessing the controller action, the `send_file` command is triggered, then we get a "File not found" in the browser, nothing gets downloaded, and the rails log shows this:

```
Sent file /srv/www/myapp/shared/tmp/directory/file.zip (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 169ms (ActiveRecord: 37.5ms)
Started GET "/srv/www/myapp/shared/tmp/directory/file.zip" for 109.190.197.126 at 2018-11-20 11:34:44 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/srv/www/myapp/shared/tmp/directory/file.zip"):
```

The file does exist and is readable but nginx can't seem to access it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the way the two `X-Accel-Mapping` are set. `Rack` is indeed able to deal with several mappings since the merge of [this PR #1187](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/1187/).

**However, as of today, this PR has been merged on master but not released yet (2.0.6 is currently the latest release)**.

The only thing is, the correct way of setting several mappings is by using one single `proxy_set_header` rule, and separate each mapping with a comma, like this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping, /var/lib/myapp/=/__working_file/,/srv/www/myapp/shared/tmp/directory/=/__new_files/
```

Answer (score 0):

while routing it is not getting . you have to provide proper route to work.